# Post request to detail_route [DRF]

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've been struggling with the POST method on a detail_route from a viewset and I don't know how to do it. I have this viewsets:

```
class ListViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.List.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.ListSerializer

    @detail_route(methods=['get'])
    def entries(self, request, pk=None):
        list = self.get_object()
        serializer = serializers.EntrySerializer(
            list.entries.all(), many=True
        )

        return Response(serializer.data)


class EntryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Entry.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.EntrySerializer
```

As you see, I did implement the `get` method on `detail_route`, but I don't know the best approach to implement the `post` method to append an entry to that specific list (like ListCreateAPIView for the detail_route).

I have that `EntryViewSet` that is going to `api/v1/entries`, but I want to be able to send a POST request that will append an entry to a specific list, that's why I want post request to `detail_route`.

I don't want the users to be sneaky and try to send an entry to a different list.

Here are the models:

```
class List(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Entry(models.Model):
    list = models.ForeignKey(List, related_name="entries")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Entries"
        unique_together = ['title', 'description']


    def __str__(self):
        return "{} from {}".format(self.title, self.list.title)
```

Thanks in advance for the answers!

Comment: You're a bit confused. You don't need separate viewsets for a single entry and a list of entries; that's the entire point of a viewset in the first place. Just use the EntryViewSet, you won't even need to define any extra methods.

Comment: But how can I specify the List for that entry if, for example, I want to add a new entry for a particular list? I know I can provide the id of that list, but I want that prefilled, I want to be able to go to /lists/1/entries/ and add a new entry for that List with id `1`, without specifying in the POST request the specific (e.g. the list with id `1`) list, how can I achieve that?

Comment: Ah sorry I had not understood that List was an actual model, I thought you just meant the list of all Entries. Why can't you have an `add_entry` method in ListViewSet?

Comment: Hmm, I will update the questions with the models, I think it's a good idea.
I don't know how to implement the `add_entry` method, I have checked the docs, but it seems kinda blurry for me, I'm a beginner. Yeah, they did provide an example: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#extra-link-and-actions, but I don't know what's going instead of those elipsis `...`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at the source code of `SimpleRouter`, it's actually pretty easy.

You can then subclass it and create your own router, adding one line to it to map the post detail route, in my example, I'm mapping it to a method called `detail_post`

```py
class DetailPostSimpleRouter(SimpleRouter):
    routes = [
        # List route.
        Route(
            url=r'^{prefix}{trailing_slash}$',
            mapping={
                'get': 'list',
                'post': 'create'
            },
            name='{basename}-list',
            detail=False,
            initkwargs={'suffix': 'List'}
        ),
        # Dynamically generated list routes. Generated using
        # @action(detail=False) decorator on methods of the viewset.
        DynamicRoute(
            url=r'^{prefix}/{url_path}{trailing_slash}$',
            name='{basename}-{url_name}',
            detail=False,
            initkwargs={}
        ),
        # Detail route.
        Route(
            url=r'^{prefix}/{lookup}{trailing_slash}$',
            mapping={
                'get': 'retrieve',
                'put': 'update',
                'patch': 'partial_update',
                'delete': 'destroy',
                'post': 'detail_post' ### here's the magic ###
            },
            name='{basename}-detail',
            detail=True,
            initkwargs={'suffix': 'Instance'}
        ),
        # Dynamically generated detail routes. Generated using
        # @action(detail=True) decorator on methods of the viewset.
        DynamicRoute(
            url=r'^{prefix}/{lookup}/{url_path}{trailing_slash}$',
            name='{basename}-{url_name}',
            detail=True,
            initkwargs={}
        ),
    ]
```

In your view set, create a method called `detail_post`.

```py
class ListViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.List.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.ListSerializer

    def detail_post(self, request, pk=None):
        # your view logic
```

Then in your `urls.py`, use our own `DetailPostSimpleRouter` instead of the `SimpleRouter`.

This is ONLY about how it can be done, whether it should be done is another topic to be discussed.

Resource:
https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/routers.py